# Django app as database web based UI

Tags: python, django

I'm planning to develop web UI something like iSQL*Plus-oracle but, for most common databases. Just take input query from user and return result with save options,etc.

So, for connecting to external data bases, what is advisable way,
1. Using django model and [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/) or,
2. with modules outside django - sqlalchemy+mysqldb,psycopg..?

Going through django documentation my understanding is db connections has to be in settings.py and I could not add from user input. Is my understanding is true or not?

I'm new to django not to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ORM (something like Django's models or sqlalchemy) is a really helpful abstraction to help map tabular data in the database to the objects its being used to model in your code. It won't help with connecting to databases provided by the user since you won't know what the schema of the database is you're connecting to, nor what you are going to receive back from a query.

With django, the database defined in settings.py is used to store information related to your app such as user credentials, migrations as well as whatever else you define in your models.py files. So definitely don't try to change that dynamically as it is being used to store the state of your application for all users.

If you need to connect to external databases and run user-supplied queries, you can do that inside a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/views/) using the appropriate database driver. So `psycopg2` for postgres would be fine.